# Error Getting Cassini to work on Local Machine

Tags: .net, windows, web-services

I get the following error when attempted to get cassini to work on a local machine:

```
The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

I actually created a BAT file to do the following

```
cd\
cd C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\
aspnet_regiis -ga "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE"
```

and was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this same thing programatically in C#. The goal is to have the installer do this without having to rely on a BAT file.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, you could invoke `aspnet_regiis` with [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

Comment: how do you get the arguements in?

Comment: @Al Katawazi You can pass the arguments by [Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx), passing the [ProcessStartInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) with [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx)